# Efficient way to set pandas DataFrame values quickly in a for loop? Possible to vectorize?

Tags: python, pandas

A quick rundown of my goal:
I am trying to make a DataFrame that contains arrays of cashflow payments. Rows are m number of loans and columns are n number of dates, and values are the associated payments on those dates, if any. My current approach is to generate the m x n DataFrame, then find each cashflow on each date of each loan and set the corresponding section of the DataFrame to that value.

```
cashflow_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = all_dates, index = all_ids)
```

I currently have a for loop that does what I want, but takes much too long to execute. I've line profiled the code:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 38.6231 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
 2                                           def frameMaker():
 3      3642      1208212    331.7      3.1      for ids, slices in id_grouped:
 4      3641         3542      1.0      0.0          data_slice = slices
 5      3641        17040      4.7      0.0          original_index = data_slice.index.values
 6      3641       583252    160.2      1.5          funded_amt = -data_slice.ix[original_index[0],'outstanding_princp_beg']
 7      3641      2091958    574.6      5.4          issue_d = data_slice.ix[original_index[0], 'issue_d']
 8      3641       346722     95.2      0.9          pmt_date_ranges = data_slice['date'].values
 9      3641       101051     27.8      0.3          date_ranges = np.append(issue_d, pmt_date_ranges)
10      3641       310452     85.3      0.8          rest_cfs = data_slice['pmt_amt_received'].values
11      3641        50856     14.0      0.1          cfs = np.append(funded_amt, rest_cfs)
12                                           
13      3641       321601     88.3      0.8          if data_slice.ix[original_index[-1], 'charged_off_recovs'] > 0:
14       412         6094     14.8      0.0              cfs[-1] = (data_slice.ix[original_index[-1], 'charged_off_recovs'] - 
15       412        35943     87.2      0.1                         data_slice.ix[original_index[-1], 'charged_off_fees'])
16                                           
17      3641     33546392   9213.5     86.9          cashflow_frame.ix[ids,date_ranges] = cfs
```

so I can see that setting the arrays in the DataFrame is the slowest. I've also noticed that it gets exponentially slower/takes a larger % Time as I have more loans. Why does it get slower and slower? What is a faster way to set values in a DataFrame? Is there a way to vectorize the operations?

I'm considering generating arrays of equal length for each loan and then creating the cashflow_frame from a (dict[loan ids] = [cashflows]), but would like to use my original code if there is a way to speed it up significantly.

More details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9V03.jpg
id_grouped is the top DataFrame grouped by 'id'. Data is read in from csv.
My code makes the lower DataFrame, which is exactly how I want it, but it takes much too long.
The first DataFrame is 8.5m rows with about 640,000 loan ids.

Comment: A sample of your input and desired output?

Comment: The general rule is to build a DataFrame in one hit. Having a DataFrame of arrays is usually not a good idea, better to just have a MultiIndex.

Comment: In order to help, some sample data of  `id_grouped` would be useful. [ask].